# How to know which constraints suffer from 'nodes are used more than once as slave node' in abaqus?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, finite-element-method, abaqus

I have been struggling to find which node and constraint suffering from 'nodes are used more than once as a slave node' in abaqus error message.

Please help me resolve this problem
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in many cases where this type error is detected during job submission a node set is created to identify the offending nodes.

open the odb in the visualization module, go into display group manager, look for node sets with names like "ERROR...." or "WARNING...".

Comment: Agentp: thanks for the comment, I knew this method, but Abaqus doesn't give specific information in which constraints those nodes because my model is complicated, the highlighted nodes from odb result visualization doesn't help.

Comment: I see, you know the node but not which constraint is causing the problem.  I think all you can do is pour through the input file to see where that node appears.